# Adding $properties to Transcluded Scope

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

I have a directive with a transcluded scope something like this:

```
<my-control>
    Some Content: {{value}}
</my-control>
```

Where `value` is coming from the parent scope.

I want to add a function that interacts with the control's scope, so I can do stuff like this:

```
<my-control>
    Some Content: {{value}}
    <button ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
</my-control>
```

Similar to the way `ngRepeat` adds properties like `$index` to the row scope. What is the easiest way to do this in my directive?

Comment: Hey there Paul! Would something like this work for you? 
http://plnkr.co/edit/SPSFGcB49qXmXROmNeHj?p=preview

Comment: @sergiocruz, I needed the directive to have an isolated scope, see accepted answer.

Comment: True... well I just want to point out the end result is the same if you add `scope: {}` to the directive declaration.  Plus a bit cleaner IMHO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we do not specify either `scope:true`(new Scope) or `scope:{}` (isolatedScope) and when we re-use the directive, the properties defined on the scope will be overridden.

For Ex:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <my-control name="myControl1">
        Some Content: {{value}} 
        My Control Name: {{name}}
    </my-control>
    <my-control name="myControl2">
        Some Content: {{value}} 
        My Control Name: {{name}}
    </my-control>
</div>
```

Instead of printing both `myControl1` and `myControl2` on the screen, it will print `myControl2` two times.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ERKSSLLRSf87Blqd0SGd?p=preview)

To overcome this issue try any of the below solutions.

**Solution1**

`transclde:true` will create a new Scope. set the properties on this scope instead of the directive's scope.

```
app.directive('myControl', function() { 
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div><p><strong>Welcome to the testMe directive!</strong></p> <div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var transclusionTarget = element[0].querySelector('[ng-transclude]').firstChild;
      var transclusionScope = angular.element(transclusionTarget).scope();
      transclusionScope.name = attrs.name;
    }
  }
});
```

here the element's under `ng-transclude` div will be compiled with the transclusionScope, grab it and update the properties in it.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1MGvo0rnVOTGImIdYdt?p=preview)

**Solution2**
Instead of using `ng-transclude`, manually transclude the content.

```
app.directive('myControl', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div><p><strong>Welcome to the testMe directive!</strong></p> <div transclude-target></div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, directiveCtrl, transcludeFn ) {

      var transclusionScope = scope.$new(),
          transclusionTarget = element[0].querySelector('[transclude-target]');

      transclusionScope.name = attrs.name;

      transcludeFn(transclusionScope, function (clone) {
        angular.element(transclusionTarget).append(clone);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here, create a `new Scope` extending the directive's scope using `scope.$new()`. And update the properties in it.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Asw8lBJXN8e8zRcnKK5b?p=preview)

**Solution1** may not work in all the cases. By the time we access `firstChild` and if it is not ready **Solution1 will fail**.

**Solution2** is cleaner and will work in all the cases.

Comment: Many thanks, solution 2 did the trick. Actually had tried something similar to this, but it seemed a bit convoluted messing with the DOM when all I wanted to do was modify the scope and I was pretty sure I was doing it wrong. I guess this is really the correct and only option.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach new methods to your scope in your directive linking function (or even in your directive's controller in case you have one).

For the sake of simplicity I will show here how to attach a new method to a directive's linking function:

```
app.directive('myControl', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function postLink(scope) {
            scope.$close = function close() {
                console.log("Close function that lives in directive...");
            };
        }
    };
});
```

In your HTML you should be able to simply to simply call that function:

```
<my-control>
    Click <a href ng-click="$close();">close</a> things.
</mycontrol>
```

Also feel to check out this plunker with the example above working in practice:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SPSFGcB49qXmXROmNeHj?p=preview

I hope this helps, and feel free to let me know if I missed anything and I will be glad to include any additional information.

Comment: If you are adding your own methods, you should avoid prefixing with '$' to be consistent with AngularJS conventions.

Comment: Hey Steve as much as I agree, I was simply trying to be consistent with Paul's question, so I wouldn't confuse him (he was asking about a $close method).

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning great libraries like angular-ui do prefix their services with a $.

Comment: Just putting it out there.

Comment: This works only because the directive isn't declaring a scope of it's own and  it's attaching the method to the inherited scope which will be accessible to both the directive and the transcluded content.  The problem being that this also means that the $close method is accessible outside of the scope of the directive.  Include two of these directives in the same parent scope and the $close method will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Vinay's answer is correct, but I'd add a twist to it to make it more "Angular"

The "angular" way to expose a directive's API is through the controller.  I'd follow the pattern that the ngForm directive uses -

Something like this:

```
app.directive('myControl', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
        this.$close = function(){
            //close me
        }
        this.$open = function() {
            //open me
        }

    }
    template: '<div><p><strong>Welcome to the testMe directive!</strong></p> <div transclude-target></div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, directiveCtrl, transcludeFn ) {

      transcludeFn(scope.$new(), function (clone, transclusionScope) {
         //only expose the API to the scope if the name attribute is present
          if(attrs.name) {
              transclusionScope[name] = directiveCtrl;
          }
          angular.element(element[0].querySelector('[transclude-target]').append(clone);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

With the usage:

```
 <my-control name="myControl2">
    <button ng-click="myControl2.$close()>Close</button>
 </my-control>
```

Comment: I think in my case using the control's name will greatly increase the odds of having a collision with the parent scope. Plus ngRepeat adds properties like $index directly to the scope, so there's an example of 'official' API that works the other way.

Comment: The point of using the "name" attribute is that it puts you in control of how the API is added to the scope - so if there is a collision, you just change the name.  Zero percent chance of collision in that case.  I don't think adding method (or properties) directly to the child scope is "wrong" either.  I have just found, through experience, that what I've suggested works well, especially if the API for the directive has more than one method or property.